Can't get full notations of public key
I try to read my public key with 6 notations from armored text by OpenPGP.js, but I got 4 notations and somehow it has same two notations each.
notations are:
gpg> showpref
[ultimate] (1). NyaightHazard (OpenPGP) <■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■>
     Cipher: AES256, AES192, AES, 3DES
     AEAD:
     Digest: SHA512, SHA384, SHA256, SHA224, SHA1
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, AEAD, Keyserver no-modify
     Notations: proof@ariadne.id=https://log.nyaight.me/o/6f698e9b9b124f69b837a617982c0156
                proof@ariadne.id=https://misskey.io/@Nyaight_Hazard
                proof@ariadne.id=dns:links.nyaight.me?type=TXT
                proof@ariadne.id=dns:nyaight.me?type=TXT
                proof@ariadne.id=https://twitter.com/NyaightHazard/status/1816532354665787521
                proof@ariadne.id=https://gist.github.com/NyaightHazard/0632dddca832ad7705049fe9d19d4dfa


I typed key=await openpgp.readKeys({armoredKeys: text}) command on browser console and result object contains [0]>users>[0]>selfCertifications: (4) [xs,xs,xs,xs] and that's notations are:
[proof@ariadne.id:https://log.nyaight.me/o/6f698e9b9b124f69b837a617982c0156],
[proof@ariadne.id:https://log.nyaight.me/o/6f698e9b9b124f69b837a617982c0156],
[proof@ariadne.id:dns:nyaight.me?type=TXT],
[proof@ariadne.id:dns:nyaight.me?type=TXT]

Is this glitch of openpgp.js or I missed something?
PS: I tried on v5.11.2 and v6(beta) but results are same.
PPS: I tried on Node.js but still same.

Hello, may I suggest you to add your code? Each selfCertification is signed, with that signature containing notations. So which selfCertification has the 4-actually-2-duplicated notations that you show? Did you have a look at rawNotations?

Yeah, I didnt know about rawNotations at that time... I still don't know why this dosen't work but I know the answer for now. Thanks.

I digged around the intetnet and find the answer.
const publicKey=await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey:publicKeyArmored });
const td=new TextDecoder();

for(const {selfCertifications} of publicKey.users){
    if(selfCertifications.length==0)continue;
    const latestCert=selfCertifications.sort((a,b)=>
        b.created.getTime()-a.created.getTime()
    )[0];
    if(latestCert.revoked)continue;
    for(const {name,value} of latestCert.rawNotations){
        console.log(`${name}=${td.decode(value)}`);
    }
}

